# Unable to Push to Github; Error 403

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am unable to push projects to Github using Android Studio. I created a new project as well as a new repository and tried pushing it to Github, but I am getting this error:

> Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 
>   https://github.com/4lionintern/Test0000.git/: The requested URL
>   **returned error: 403**

All the questions asked about this have been using git bash, but I am trying to use the commit changes button.

[image]

Comment: A quick search of https://github.com/4lionintern?tab=repositories reveals that no such repository for Test0000.git actually exists. Have you created it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I couldn't push to my own repository!

It was a problem with windows credentials.

1. Go to: `Control panel > User Accounts > credential manager`
2. select: `windows credentials`
3. Remove all gitlab credentials you see in the list
4. Add a generic credential with your gitlab account info:

Internet or network address:  `git:https://yourUserName@gitlab.com`

username: `your gitlab username`

password: `your gitlab password`

then try to push your changes to the repository again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide write permission to your team member
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UygFK.jpg) 
go to member repository permission

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the path of git URL from https to SSH, then to reload the project again. Then try to push. Also check credentials given in   File>Settings>Version Control>Github

Answer (score 0):

403 means, that your credentials are wrong or not existing. How are you authenticating at Github? Via Username:Password or public Key. If you use public key, this is not possible via https.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `project folder` and Delete `.git` folder, then try again. If it does not work. Your repository URL may be wrong or the authentication problem.

Comment: After you delete  .git folder, try to "Share project on GitHub".  it will create a new repository on github and push your code over there..

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS doesn't work with Android Studio. I tried re-initializing git using git bash.

In your root folder. Delete old non-working `.git` folder:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Initialize a new empty Git repository. Then add files you want to commit

```
git init
git add .
```

Commit and push

```
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:YourNameHere/YourProjectName.git
git push -u origin master
```

After that, git should work in Android Studio.

1. VCS > Git > Commit File...
2. VCS > Git > Push

Answer (score 0):

You need to first go to: Setting -->System Settings --> passwords --> Select Don't save password.

Next time when you click push, you will be asked for username and password for git repository.Enter your credentials and continue.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 means : Access not granted.
Means github has understood your request but denied your changes

The problem generally occurs when the gitbash account and the github credentials in your android studio do not match. You might have changed the username and password in your android studio but the account in the gitbash remains the same. So you should change the credentials of your gitbash in accordance to the android studio credentials.
Change the gitbash credentials in accordance with the android studio credentials and it will definitely work.